# wxpython OSX: large numbers of wx.Notebook tabs are inaccessible

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

Writing a GUI using wxPython for OSX and Linux/X, and I'm running into an issue in which, if I've got a significant number of notebook tabs, I can't get the wx.Dialog or wx.Frame or wx.Panel containing the wx.Notebook to expand to show them all (wx.EXPAND does not appear to do anything)

Under Linux/X, this isn't an issue, as it produces little arrows that let you go from tab to tab ([see illustration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBNYz.png)). But under OSX my users get screwed, because the tabs are drawn off the edge of the panel and are completely inaccessible ([illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRal5.png)).

Sample code used to create the above examples:

```
import wx

class TempFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Temp Frame")

        self.notebook = wx.Notebook(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.BK_DEFAULT)
        for num in range(0, 11):
            notepanel = TempPanel(self.notebook, num)
            self.notebook.AddPage(notepanel, str(num))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.notebook, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()

class TempPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, num):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.title = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, str(num))

        self.test_list = ["One", "One", "Two", "Three", "Five", "Eight"]
        self.test_choice = wx.Choice(self, wx.ID_ANY, choices=self.test_list)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.title, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.test_choice, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = TempFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Is there any way to tell wxPython to make enough space for all of the notebook tabs?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried by setting manually the proportion flag when adding the panel to the sizer?

Comment: @MatteoD Did so, and it had no effect.

Comment: Does the wxPython demo behave the same way when you resize it? On Windows, when I resize it to be too small, the arrows just appear and I can get to them that way. Also which wxPython version are you using?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll It does behave the same way when resizing, alas. And I'm on wxPython 2.8.12.1; haven't had the chance to try later versions.
(also, sorry for delay; was away from my OSX computer for the weekend :D )

Comment: I would ask on the wxPython users group or the wxPython-mac user group or both.

Comment: Somehow I had managed not to notice that such user groups existed, and further searching of those has been helpful; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Further research has revealed that this is a native-widgets limitation in OSX. To [quote Robin Dunn](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wxpython-users/DuHQT8D0DSY/LuaPu7lO8ZoJ):

> The native tab control does not support it.  Apparently the UI 
>   designers at Apple feel that there should never be more than about half 
>   a dozen tabs on any layout, and that if more pages are needed then there 
>   is something wrong with the UI.

Fortunately, that same reply notes the existence of Listbook (of which I was not aware) and other, related controls that serve just as well. After going through [a very helpful blog entry on those controls](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/), I ended up going with Choicebook, which works just fine for my purposes on OSX.

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue!